# pyramid - threadlocal doesn't work inside Response's app_iter

Tags: python, pyramid, thread-local, webob

With the following sample code:

```
from webob import Response
from paste.httpserver import serve


def test_iter():
    from pyramid import threadlocal
    yield 'current request: %s' % threadlocal.get_current_request()


def hello_world(request):
    return Response(app_iter=test_iter())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pyramid.config import Configurator
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_view(hello_world)
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

I get *current request: None*. So, `threadlocal` doesn't work inside `app_iter`? I have actual code where I need to access `threadlocal` several layers away from the view, and it would be cumbersome to pass the `request` variable around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Pyramid docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/narr/router.html) the thread-local stack shouldn't be popped until after app_iter is used (see steps 16 and 18), although I see the same behavior as you when I try to run your example.  Since the documentation and behavior conflict one of them is wrong, I recommend [filing a bug](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/issues) with the Pyramid folks.

Comment: Ah, that's actually the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe mistake?

```
return Response(app_iter=test_iter())
```

or

```
return Response(app_iter=test_iter)
```

Comment: `app_iter` expects an iterator. Passing in just `test_iter` will cause error `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`.